# Angular and jQuery: Load component dynamically

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-confirm

I'm using the [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) plugin with Angular 6, and I can open alerts and dialogs with static content:

```
<button (click)="openConfirm()">Open Confirm</button>
```

```
openConfirm() {
  $.confirm({
    title: 'Test',
    content: 'It works!'
  });
}
```

Now I want to load a component inside, and I thought if I pass the selector in a string I would load it. But it didn't.

I think the plugin uses the jquery html() function to add html to the confirm box. Because when I tried this:

```
$.confirm({
  title: 'Test',
  content: '<app-confirm></app-confirm>'
});
```

I checked and the plugin actually added the selectors to the html, but it didn't load the component.

Comment: Why don't you use an angular modal component instead of trying to use jQuery? Anyway, what you are trying to do won't work. If would need to use something like the Dynamic Component Loader (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) but this seems so wrong for me (try to handle DOM with jQuery inside an angular app).

Comment: Yes, I know it won't work, I'm using this plugin because I like the style and design, and I have always use it in another projects. Anyway, I'm trying to see if there's some way of making this work.